# Use the relevance score of FULLTEXT search in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple fulltext search query:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(col1,col2,col3) AGAINST ('keywords' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relev FROM table1 ORDER BY relev DESC
```

Which technically works but it also returns results with a relevance of 0.

I tried to use:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(col1,col2,col3) AGAINST ('keywords' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relev FROM table1 WHERE relev > 0 ORDER BY relev DESC
```

but that tells me that `relev` is an invalid column name.

Is there any way to exclude results with a `relev` of 0 without having to use `MATCH(..) AGAINST(..)` again within the `WHERE` clause?  Doesn't doing that basically repeat the fulltext search again and take twice as much time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause instead:

```
SELECT t.*,
       MATCH(col1, col2, col3) AGAINST ('keywords' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relev
FROM table1 t
HAVING relev > 0
ORDER BY relev DESC;
```

SQL (in general) does not allow the use of column aliases in the `WHERE` clause.  MySQL does, however, allow them in the `HAVING` clause (not all databases do).  This can be convenient for a situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

[The MySql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) imply the use of `HAVING` is going to result in filtering only after the evaluation of all relevance scores.

> The HAVING clause is applied nearly last, just before items are sent to the client, with no optimization. (LIMIT is applied after HAVING.)

and

> Do not use HAVING for items that should be in the WHERE clause.

The performance of the repeated `MATCH()` [is actually better](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

> To achieve this result, you should specify MATCH() twice: once in the SELECT list and once in the WHERE clause. This causes no additional overhead, because the MySQL optimizer notices that the two MATCH() calls are identical and invokes the full-text search code only once.

My experiments and [this other StackOverflow QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245974/alternative-mysql-fulltext-search-syntax#answer-2246217) confirm this.

I also tried to use an inner query

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT textColumn, MATCH(textColumn) AGAINST('searchWord' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance
  FROM table
)
WHERE relevance > 0
```

which had a performance as poor as the `HAVING` version.

The reason I wished to have an alternative was not repeating myself in the query - DRY.

Unfortunately I think it is not possible to avoid repeating oneself with no performance penalty, so in the end I chose the double `MATCH() AGGAINST()`.